# Lost/Stolen Passport but travel is before the 1 week fast-track service UK

Tags: passports, new-zealand, belgium, lost-documents

My mum was in Brussels for the day and had her bag stolen with passport in it.  She is due to fly out this coming Friday (1 week today) to New Zealand to spend Christmas with me.

The police assisted her with getting her back on the Eurostar from Brussels to London so she will be back in the UK without a passport to travel with next Friday.

I have made the appointment online and the first available appointment is Wednesday at 9:15 am.  The website says:

> 1 week fast-track service for lost/stolen passports from the day of appointment

(i.e. would be a week from next Wednesday!!!!).

She has the following supporting documents/proof to take to the appointment on Wednesday:

- Copy of stolen passport
- Police Report - Brussels
- Proof of travel to NZ on Friday

Is there **any way** they will allow her to pay for an expedited service to get her passport that same day? (I've seen the other same day services they offer but not for this particular circumstance!)...  Or will she be forced to abort her travel plans to fly to NZ for Christmas with me?  #heartbreak.

I am so stressed out and I cannot seem to find anything on the government website where they address the issue of traveling**before** the 1-week fast-track service...

If anyone has been in this position or has any information to give me, I would be so grateful as I literally feel like I'm going to be sick.

Thank you and Merry Christmas.

Comment: `Is there any way they will allow her to pay for an expedited service to get her passport that same day?` The [UK.GOV website](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently) seems pretty clear that for lost/stolen passports, the best you can get is the 1 week Fast Track. I believe for stolen passports they need time to do some reviewing of the paperwork and voiding the stolen passport etc.

Comment: There are faster services, but they do not seem to be applicable for replacing a lost passport. However the government’s advice is to call the [Passport adviceline](https://www.gov.uk/passport-advice-line) on 0300 222 0000 in such a situation, they may be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: @jcaron that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @CLL how did things turn out? Did you call the passport adviceline? Where they able to help?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's too late to help in this specific case, the following information will be useful for any other British citizens in a similar situation. (I'm guessing this case refers to a British citizen, since the asker refers to their mother returning to London prior to a planned visit to New Zealand.)

In the event that a passport is stolen, a British citizen can obtain an emergency travel document if there is insufficient time to obtain a replacement passport before planned travels. For details, see https://www.gov.uk/emergency-travel-document